# Django dynamic fields - cannot get data from multiples added rows from Template

Tags: javascript, python, django, templates, dynamic

I am working on a template that generate dynamically multiple rows.

When i submit the form I cannot get all the generated row from the template. Only the last one is saved.

I think I am missing something to get the data from the generated rows.

Here is my code :

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    contractNumber = models.ForeignKey('SupportContract', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    serialNumber = models.CharField(max_length=800, null=True)
    reference = models.ForeignKey('ProductDescription', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.serialNumber) if self.serialNumber else ''
```

**form.py**

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    contractNumber = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=SupportContract.objects.all().order_by('number'), label='contractNumber', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Contract number'}))
    serialNumber = forms.CharField(required=True, label='serialNumber',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Enter serial number'}))
    reference = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=ProductDescription.objects.all().order_by('name'), label='reference',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Product descrition'}))
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(initial=1, required=True, label='quantity',widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Enter a quantity'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        contractNumber = self.cleaned_data.get('contract_number')
        serialNumber = self.cleaned_data.get('serial_number')
        reference = self.cleaned_data.get('product_reference')
        quantity = self.cleaned_data.get('quantity')

ProductFormset = formset_factory(ProductForm, extra=1)
```

**template.html**

```
<div data-role="dynamic-fields">
    {{ form_Product.management_form }}
    <div class="form-inline"  style="margin-left: -15px">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            {{ form_Product.quantity }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            {{ form_Product.serialNumber }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-role="remove">
        <span class="fas fa-minus"></span>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-role="add">
        <span class="fas fa-plus"></span>
    </button>
</div></div></div>
```

**views.py**

```
def form_exhibit_c(request):

    template_name = 'supportContract/ExhibitCtemplate.html'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formset = ProductFormset(request.GET or None)
        form_SupportContract = SupportContractForm(request.GET or None)
        form_ProductDescription = ProductDescriptionForm(request.GET or None)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ProductFormset(request.POST)
        form_SupportContract = SupportContractForm(request.POST)
        form_ProductDescription = ProductDescriptionForm(request.POST)

        form_SupportContract.save(commit=False)
        form_ProductDescription.save(commit=False)

        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                serialNumber = form.cleaned_data.get('serialNumber')

                if serialNumber :
                    p = Product.objects.create(serialNumber=serialNumber, quantity='1')
    else:
        form_SupportContract = SupportContractForm()
        form_ProductDescription = ProductDescriptionForm()
        formset = ProductForm()

    return render(request, template_name, {'form_Product' : formset, 'form_ProductDescription': form_ProductDescription, 'form_SupportContract' : form_SupportContract})
```

**dynamicFields.js**

```
    // Remove button click
    $(document).on(
        'click',
        '[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-inline [data-role="remove"]',
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('.form-inline').remove();
        });
    // Add button click
    $(document).on(
        'click',
        '[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-inline [data-role="add"]',
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var container = $(this).closest('[data-role="dynamic-fields"]');
            new_field_group = container.children().filter('.form-inline:first-child').clone();
            new_field_group.find('input').each(function(){
                if (this.name == 'quantity') {
                    $(this).val('1');
                }else{
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            });
            container.append(new_field_group);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work adding increment/decrement for IDs form in the js.

code below :

```
$(function() {
    function updateIdForm(container, nb_fields){
        field_group = container.children().filter('.form-inline:visible');
        var cpt = 0;
        var flag_input = 0;
        field_group.find('input').each(function(){
            if(flag_input >= nb_fields){
                cpt++;
                flag_input=0;
            };
            flag_input++;
            var input = $(this);
            var name = input.attr('name').split('-', 3);
            var id = input.attr('id').split('-', 3);
            $(this).attr('id', id[0] + '-' + cpt + '-' + id[2]);
            $(this).attr('name', name[0] + '-' + cpt + '-' + name[2]);
        });
    };

    function countFields(container, row_nb_row){
        var l_cpt=0;
        field_group = container.children().filter('.form-inline:visible');
        field_group.find('input').each(function(){
            l_cpt++;
        });
        var fields = l_cpt/(row_nb_row+1);
        return fields;
    };

    var nb_row = 0;

    // Remove button click
    $(document).on(
        'click',
        '[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-inline [data-role="remove"]',
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var container = $(this).closest('[data-role="dynamic-fields"]');
            $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt($('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val()) - 1);
            var nb_fields = countFields(container, nb_row);
            $(this).closest('.form-inline').remove();
            updateIdForm(container, nb_fields);
            nb_row--;
        }
    );
    // Add button click
    $(document).on(
            'click',
            '[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-inline [data-role="add"]',
            function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                nb_row++;
                var container = $(this).closest('[data-role="dynamic-fields"]');
                new_field_group = container.children().filter('.form-inline:first-child').clone();
                new_field_group.find('input').each(function(){
                    var input = $(this);
                    var name = input.attr('name').split('-', 3);
                    var id = input.attr('id').split('-', 3);
                    $(this).attr('id', id[0] + '-' + nb_row + '-' + id[2] )
                    $(this).attr('name', name[0] + '-' + nb_row + '-' + name[2] )
                    $(this).val('');
                });
                $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt($('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val()) + 1);
                container.append(new_field_group);
                var nb_fields = countFields(container, nb_row);
                updateIdForm(container, nb_fields);
            });
});
```